# How to check if a user device is using fingerprint/face as unlock method. [ReactNative] [Expo]

Tags: react-native, fingerprint, expo, touch-id, face-id

I'm using ReactNative based on Expo Toolkit to develop a App and I want know how I can check if the user is using the fingerprint (TouchID on iPhone) or face detection (FaceID on iPhone X>) to unlock the device.

I already know how to check if device has the required hardware using Expo SDK, as follow:

```
let hasFPSupport = await Expo.Fingerprint.hasHardwareAsync();
```

But I need check if the user choose the fingerprint/face as unlock method on your device, instead pattern or pin.

Thanks

Comment: This is currently not part of the Expo SDK.

Comment: Do you know either a lib or other trick to do this? Even without using expo? Thank you so much. ;]

Comment: Hey @RodrigoTessarollo - I know this is an old question, but if you're still looking, you can determine if they have Face ID by checking the device type. Posted more details below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can check if device has scanned fingerprints:

```
await Expo.Fingerprint.isEnrolledAsync()
```

So, this can be used to reach the objective as follow:

```
let hasFPSupport = await Expo.Fingerprint.hasHardwareAsync() && await Expo.Fingerprint.isEnrolledAsync();
```

Comment: Expo.Fingerprint is deprecated and replaced with Expo.LocalAuthentication

Comment: Thanks for the update, the new expo releases enhanced the FP api. Now is quite easy get things works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an update to Donald's answer that takes into account Expo's empty string for the model name of the new iPhone XS. It also takes into account the Simulator.

```
const hasHardwareSupport =
  (await Expo.LocalAuthentication.hasHardwareAsync()) &&
  (await Expo.LocalAuthentication.isEnrolledAsync());

let hasTouchIDSupport
let hasFaceIDSupport

if (hasHardwareSupport) {
  if (Constants.platform.ios) {
    if (
      Constants.platform.ios.model === '' ||
      Constants.platform.ios.model.includes('X')
    ) {
      hasFaceIDSupport = true;
    } else {
      if (
        Constants.platform.ios.model === 'Simulator' &&
        Constants.deviceName.includes('X')
      ) {
        hasFaceIDSupport = true;
      }
    }
  }
   hasTouchIDSupport = !hasFaceIDSupport;
}
```

**EDIT**: Expo released an update that fixes the blank model string. However you might want to keep a check for that just in case the next iPhone release cycle causes the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you could determine that a user has Face ID by checking `Expo.Fingerprint.hasHardwareAsync()` and `Expo.Fingerprint.isEnrolledAsync()`, and then also checking that they have an iPhone X using `Expo.Constants.platform` ([docs here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants#expoconstantsplatform)).

So:

```
const hasHardwareSupport = await Expo.Fingerprint.hasHardwareAsync() && await Expo.Fingerprint.isEnrolledAsync();`
if (hasHardwareSupport) {
  const hasFaceIDSupport = Expo.Constants.platform.ios && Expo.Constants.platform.ios.model === 'iPhone X';
  const hasTouchIDSupport = !hasFaceIDSupport;
}
```

Comment: This might get fixed later, but current XS phones have a blank string as their model. This answer needs updating.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you tried the above answer and it's not working please note as at the time of my post expo's documentation has changed

```
- import * as LocalAuthentication from 'expo-local-authentication';
- let compatible = await LocalAuthentication.hasHardwareAsync()
```